# Easy way to get crayon out of grout?

Tags: bathroom, cleaning, grout

My daughter decided to get a little artistic in the bathroom and colored the grout with yellow crayon. Does anyone have a simple way to clean this out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ALL of the grout? If so, I'd say scraping and re-grouting would likely be easiest solution.

If it's just in a few spots, you could try the brown paper bag + iron technique: cover the area with a layer or two of brown paper bag and then apply a hot iron to it. The heat of the iron will melt the wax and the paper bag will then wick it up. Try on a small section, first.

Comment: Your technique worked pretty well. I hit it with a heat gun and then wiped it with a paper towel. There was a little residue remaining, but it's light yellow and matches the rest of the grout fairly well. At least it wasn't blue.

Answer (score 2):

Goof off, tile brush and elbow grease.

[image]
<sub>(source: [nydailynews.com](http://assets.nydailynews.com/img/2007/06/14/amd_goofoff.jpg))</sub>
[image]
<sub>(source: [labsafety.com](http://www.labsafety.com/images/xl/Iron-Handle-Scrub-Brush-LSS-_i_lbw157705S.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can also get "grout refresher" basically typex for grout that you paint over the old yellowed grout before you sell the house ;-)

Comment: Painting over the grout seems extreme, unless it never came out, which it very well should. But this is a great solution for extreme stains.